# Find the second highest value

Tags: pascal

I've wrote this Code to find out the second highest value in an Array:

```
var
 i,
 ZweitMax,
  Max : integer;

begin
Max := -maxint;
ZweitMax := -maxint;

for i := 1 to FELDGROESSE do


if inFeld[i] > Max then
  begin
  ZweitMax := Max;
  Max := inFeld[i];
  end
else
if inFeld[i] > ZweitMax then
begin
ZweitMax := inFeld[i];
FeldZweitMax := ZweitMax;
end
end;
```

Where is the Problem in this Code and why it don't print out the right value? 
Information: The Code is part of a function FeldZweitMax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are currently *two* places where you set `ZweitMax` but only *one* of them also affects the return code of the function, `FeldZweitMax`.

The first part of the `if` statement can be changed into:

```
if inFeld[i] > Max then
begin
    ZweitMax := Max;
    FeldZweitMax := ZweitMax;  (* add this line *)
    Max := inFeld[i];
end
(* and so on *)
```

so as to ensure the return value is updated correctly.

Alternatively, you can just set `ZweitMax` alone in both places and then set the return value at the end:

```
for i := 1 to FELDGROESSE do
begin
    if inFeld[i] > Max then
    begin
        ZweitMax := Max;
        Max := inFeld[i];
    end
    else
    begin
        if inFeld[i] > ZweitMax then
        begin
            ZweitMax := inFeld[i];
        end
    end
end;
FeldZweitMax := ZweitMax;
```

I actually prefer the latter since the calculation and return of the value are separate matters.

Comment: Ok, it means i need to Change the begin/end?